# Is is true to say $F(x) = ma(x)$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, calculus

Considering the equation $F(t) = ma(t)$, I'm trying to figure out if the following is also always true:

$$F(x(t)) = m\cdot a(x(t))$$

I.e.: $F$ as a function of $X$ (the position, which itself is a function of time) is equal to the mass times the acceleration (which is a function of $X$).

It seems mathematically to me like it should be correct, but I'm unsure and would like to validate.

Also: Which of the following equations is correct?

$$a(x(t)) = \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x(t))}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Or rather:

$$a(x(t)) = \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x(t))}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you seek is not true.**  It can't be true if your object might ever revisit the same position twice with different forces on it.

Part of the challenge is in notation.  It's more obvious what's going on if we're careful with variable names.  You start with $F(t)=ma(t)$.  This works perfectly.  It's just a time varying force.  However, when you sought to switch to a function of position, you kept the variable names the same: $F(x(t))=ma(x(t))$  $F$ was a function of time and $a$ was a function of time.  Thus they *cannot* be a property of distance.  To keep ourselves consistent and sane, we need to come up with new variables.  It's common to use the "prime" symbol to capture the idea of a new something.  So we can define a new function $F^\prime(x(t)) = ma^\prime(x(t))$.  Now that we're consistent, we can ask if this is true.

We can show that its trivially false by trying to work our way backwards.  If this were true, we should be able to create an inverse function $x^{-1}$ mapping from position to time such that $F(x^{-1}(t)) = ma(x^{-1}(t))$.  Note that this is really close to the equation you had earlier.  The difference is that $x^{-1}$ is a function from positions to times, so $F$ and $a$ still being consistently treated as a function of time.

And herein lies the problem - your function $x(t)$ needs to be invertible for the property you seek to hold.  What if your object revists the same $x$ position twice?  In the time based equation for $F(t)$, they can have different forces and accelerations at those two times.  However, in the latter equation, $F^\prime(x)$, we see the object must have the same force at both of those times.

As a concrete example, consider a bowling ball swinging back and forth on a rope -- a pendulum.  At some time when the bowling ball is near its maximum, you slide a concrete wall into its path at the lowest point.  That ball is going to come down and be subject to sudden forces when it impacts.  But it will have to experience those forces at a position it has swung through many times before.

And note that while the equation you wrote will be true if $x(t)$ is invertible, the usual equations for position and velocity will be slightly different.  You will not be able to simply write $v(x(t)) = a(x(t))t+v_0$ or $x=\frac 1 2 a(x(t))t^2 + v_0t + x_0$.  While $F=ma$ is simply the definition of what a force is, and can be treated simply as a look-up function of time or space, velocity and positions are calculated using calculus.  Calculus has a [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) which you need to use when integrating or taking the derivative (which are the operations that go between positions, velocities, and accelerations).  That rule affects how you go about changing variables (such as from time to space).

Comment: Excellent points! One can indeed specify a unique $\vec F(x(t))$, however, one cannot say: given a *path* what is $\vec F(t(x))$?

Answer (score 1):

I am disconcerted to see that two answers agree with
your equation
$$F(x(t)) = m\cdot a(x(t)).\tag{1}$$

@CortAmmon 's answer hit the nail. I want to address the conceptual mistake behind equation $(1)$ more directly.

If one sticks at the algebraic level, it would be possible to say that, since acceleration is proportional to the force, if the force is a function of $x(t)$, then $a$ should have the same dependence on time.

However, this reading of the equation is purely algebraic. It is equivalent to using the acceleration $a$ as a synonymous of $F/m$ without adding any new information to the expression of the force. Such a reading completely misses the critical concept that equations of motion are **differential equations**. I.e., the symbol $a$ is a shortened notation for
$$
a = \frac{{\mathrm d}^2x}{{\mathrm d}t^2},
$$
where $x$, and then $a$ are functions of $t$. If you look at these facts, you'll understand the general nonsense of introducing a functional dependence of $a$ on $x$. It would be equivalent to saying that the first derivative of a generic function $f(t)$ is a function of $t$ through $f$. In some cases, the $t$ dependence of $f$ could be inverted. But they are not generic cases, and, more importantly, such a rewriting doesn't help solve differential equations.

Indeed, the correct way of looking at the general Newton's equation of motion is to write it as
$$
\frac{{\mathrm d}^2x}{{\mathrm d}t^2} = \frac{1}{m}F\left(x(t),\frac{{\mathrm d}x}{{\mathrm d}t}(t),t\right)
$$
Where the unknown function $x(t)$ has a second derivative (with respect to time) proportional to a function (the force $F$) depending on time implicitly, through $x$ and its first derivative, and also explicitly.

Comment: Excellent point! I was thinking of one thing (that it is possible to write *force* as a parametrized function of $x(t)$, while doing another (writing about Newton's second law).  Let it be hereby known that the answer given by Albertus Magnus is absolute non-sense!!

Comment: Let is also be known that OP's post was not so clear before revisions, editing, etc. After all, if one must eat crow, it doesn't hurt to add a little salt!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dv}{dx}$ doesn't really make sense since $v = \frac{x}{t}$ so $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{t}$ so if you for some reason labeled acceleration as $\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{1}{t}$ you'd have units $\frac{m}{t}\frac{\text{kg}}{\text{seconds}}$ where as $ma = \frac{m dv}{dt}$ gives you $\text{kg}\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$ which makes more sense since it's the quantity describing how much mass is moving per second per second.

Answer (score -1):

This is correct.

So long as mass remains constant, which seems to be the case, this is a valid equation to write

Force is defined as rate of change of momentum, and given mass constant, acceleration is rate of change of velocity. None of these is violated by acceleration depending on position

To give an example, in a spring mass system performing oscillations, we will write F= -kx where k is the force constant of the spring and x is displacement from mean position. It is from this equation that the time dependence of position can be derived. Incidentally it comes out to be sinusoidal.